# Sync XAMPP Files With Dropbox on mac

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, dropbox

When I change the file path in the httpd.config to
`/User/username/dropbox/htdocks`, I get the error in the web browser:

> Access forbidden!
>   You don't have permission to access the requested directory. 
>   There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 403
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2g PHP/5.6.19 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

Answer (score 2):

I solved this same problem changing the permissions of the Dropbox folder. My Dropbox had the permissions set to `drwx------` and to make it work I changed to `drwxr-xr-x`

To see files and folders permissions type this in the Terminal

```
ls -laG
```

the result will be a list of file and folders with the permissions string at the beginning of each line

To change the permissions type this in the terminal:

```
chmod go+rx Dropbox
```

Don't know if is the best solution but it works